# Batch file for 2 level protection RDP connection

Tags: file, batch-file

I am creating a batch file to open a RDP session.
The remote desktop uses a gateway, so there are 2 credentials to be entered.
One for the gateway and other for the remote desktop.

I have written the following code:-

cmdkey /generic:gateway/abc.com /user:user1 /pass:password1

cmdkey /generic:TREMSRV/10.2.13.4 /user:user2 /pass:password2

start mstsc /v:10.2.13.4

But on running this code the pop to enter first set of credentials appears. I want to hardcode the credentials in the batch file itself

Can anyone suggest how shall i accomplish this ?

Comment: I would assume you do not need the /generic option for the gateway.

Comment: Yes true. Could help me find how can I save the 2 level credentials for this server.